# method adding object to array is adding from index 1 not 0

Tags: java, arrays

Method adding Task object, a simple object with a string and an int, to array is adding from index 1 not 0.

How do I correct this without rewriting the method from scratch??

This is the professor's method and there is other interdependent code in the program.  He said there's a 'small' issue here I need to fix. The issue seems to be that the method is adding from index 1 not 0. Is there a small, minimally invasive fix to this small issue.

I dont understand why pos /= 2 is used, if this is relevant.

```
  public void insert( String job, int priority )
  {
     Task newJob = new Task( job, priority );

     heap[++heapSize] = newJob;

     int pos = heapSize;

     while (( pos != 1 ) && ( newJob.priority > heap[pos/2].priority ))
     {
        heap[pos] = heap[pos/2];
        pos /=2;
     }
     heap[pos] = newJob;    
  }
```

I have tried:

```
( pos != 0 )
( pos != 2 )
```

and deleting

```
( pos != 1 )
```

These cause NullPointerExceptions.

Comment: This `heap[++heapSize] = newJob;` should be `heap[heapSize++] = newJob;` - it's important to understand the difference between pre and post increment. Alternatively, modify the initial value of `heapSize` from `0` to `-1`.

Comment: heap[heapSize++] = newJob; is the fix. ++variable will increment the variable first. That's why it starts with 1.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes,  this is what the professor said.  This notation was new to me and I didn't understand the difference between ++I and I++. Now I do. I'll have to look at it a nuit more to understand why this caused the issue,  but I still need to complete the assignment if I can understand what it is.